# How to avoid borrowing a value that was moved into a closure without using clone?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand the closures in Rust. I wrote a code like this;

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn main() {
    let mut a = "a string".to_string();

    let mut cl = ||  {
        a.add(" another string");
    };

    cl();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

I expect a result like "a string another string". In the documentation it says that try to avoid using `clone()` where possible, but I can't manage to  compile this code without using `a = a.clone().add(" another string")`.

Comment: It's possible you have a wrong design here. I'm not sure how you mean to use your closure (for example you can't declare two of them this way).

Comment: `add` moves (i.e. consumes) `a` and returns the result as a value, it is not intended for modifying `a`. This is because it is the underlying function for the `+` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>To answer your original question: You can't. This is because your string `a` is moved into the closure. You can't have it back though.</strike> See [Denys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021028/1021920) for a solution.

---

A solution to this specific problem would be to use `push_str` instead of `Add`, because `push_str` requires a mutable referece instead of a moved value.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = "a string".to_string();

    let mut cl = || {
        a.push_str(" another string");
    };

    cl();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know 'push_str'. Because of push_str requires reference closure doesn't take ownership of a? Right?

Comment: You can also use the `+=` operator: `a += " another string";`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to move the value to the closure, then make it return it:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn main() {
    let mut a = "a string".to_string();
    let cl = ||  {
        a.add(" another string")
    };
    a = cl();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

But capturing the outer scope is rather limited. You can't for example have two closures defined this way. You might want a more flexible solution:

```
let a = "a string".to_string();
let c1 = |s: String|  {
    s.add(" another string")
};
let c2 = |s: String|  {
    s + " and another one"
};
let a = c1(a);
let a = c2(a);
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is making closure to change its outer scope. But this is also a good answer. If my closure doesn't reserved to return something else I can use this way also.

Comment: You should probably use functions and don't try to capture the outer scope: the mutable reference can't be borrowed in several closures.

Comment: Oh I got it. I just tried and you're right. Multiple mutable borrow is impossible between closures. I'm just trying to understand the effects of closure to its outer scope when it borrows or captures the values. Thanks for your point. I understood that I shouldn't use closures to change their outer scope.